# Adding TypeScript types for a 3rd party Svelte module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, svelte, svelte-component

I'm using svelte-calendar@2.0.4 and it has no TypeScript definitions.

I tried adding the type definitions below to my global.d.ts but am getting a warning in VS Code

> JSX element type 'Datepicker' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604) on the instance of the Datepicker:

```html
<Datepicker bind:selected={selectedDate} {start} class="btn btn-sm">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary date-picker">{selectedDateString}</button>
</Datepicker>
```

Added to **global.d.ts**...

```js
declare module 'svelte-calendar' {
  interface DatepickerProps
    extends svelte.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElementTagNameMap['div']> {
    format?: string
    start?: Date
    end?: Date
    selected?: Date
    dateChosen?: boolean
    trigger?: () => void
    selectableCallback?: () => void
    weekStart?: number
    daysOfWeek?: Array<string, string>
    monthsOfYear?: Array<string, string>
    style?: string
    buttonBackgroundColor?: string
    buttonBorderColor?: string
    buttonTextColor?: string
    highlightColor?: string
    dayBackgroundColor?: string
    dayTextColor?: string
    dayHighlightedBackgroundColor?: string
    dayHighlightedTextColor?: string
  }
  export class Datepicker extends SvelteComponentTyped<DatepickerProps> {}
}
```

based on the [Datepicker.svelte sources](https://github.com/6eDesign/svelte-calendar/blob/master/src/Components/Datepicker.svelte).

I've never tried adding types for a 3rd party component. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As a workaround, try `import Datepicker from 'svelte-calendar/src/Components/Datepicker.svelte'`. There is also a similar issue: https://github.com/6eDesign/svelte-calendar/issues/119

Comment: Thanks - that is a nice workaround! The issue logged for svelte-calendar was from me ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare module 'svelte-calendar' {
  import { SvelteComponentTyped } from 'svelte'; 
  interface DatepickerProps
    extends svelte.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElementTagNameMap['div']> {
    format?: string
    start?: Date
    end?: Date
    selected?: Date
    dateChosen?: boolean
    trigger?: () => void
    selectableCallback?: () => void
    weekStart?: number
    daysOfWeek?: Array<string, string>
    monthsOfYear?: Array<string, string>
    style?: string
    buttonBackgroundColor?: string
    buttonBorderColor?: string
    buttonTextColor?: string
    highlightColor?: string
    dayBackgroundColor?: string
    dayTextColor?: string
    dayHighlightedBackgroundColor?: string
    dayHighlightedTextColor?: string
  }
  export default class Datepicker extends SvelteComponentTyped<DatepickerProps> {}
}
```

You need to add the `export default class` for it to work..

Answer (score 1):

Your definition was almost correct. You need to import `SvelteComponentTyped` within your module declaration, else TS doesn't know what you extend from.

```typescript
declare module 'svelte-calendar' {
  import { SvelteComponentTyped } from 'svelte'; // <<<--- added
  interface DatepickerProps
    extends svelte.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElementTagNameMap['div']> {
    format?: string
    start?: Date
    end?: Date
    selected?: Date
    dateChosen?: boolean
    trigger?: () => void
    selectableCallback?: () => void
    weekStart?: number
    daysOfWeek?: Array<string, string>
    monthsOfYear?: Array<string, string>
    style?: string
    buttonBackgroundColor?: string
    buttonBorderColor?: string
    buttonTextColor?: string
    highlightColor?: string
    dayBackgroundColor?: string
    dayTextColor?: string
    dayHighlightedBackgroundColor?: string
    dayHighlightedTextColor?: string
  }
  export class Datepicker extends SvelteComponentTyped<DatepickerProps> {}
}
```

Note that you need at least Svelte 3.31 for this (`SvelteComponentTyped` was added in that version).

Comment: Thanks - I added this to my global.d.ts. In my Schedule.svelte where I import and use 'svelte-calendar', I get a red underline below the instance of Datepicker with the message "JSX element type 'Datepicker' does not have any construct or call signatures." I'm using Svelte 3.44.2.